# What is Memcached::isPristine() used for in PHP?

Tags: php, memcached

I've stumbled across [`Memcached::isPristine()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.ispristine.php) while reading the docs regarding Memcached but got no idea what is it for.

I could notice it's linked to persistent connections but the documentation lacks those example use cases that are usually present in other pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain it with an example

```
$m1 = new MemCached('test');
$m1->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$m2 = new MemCached('test');
$m2->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

var_dump($m2->getServerList());
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["port"]=>
    int(11211)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["port"]=>
    int(11211)
  }
}
```

With isPristine

```
$m1 = new MemCached('test');
$m1->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
$m2 = new MemCached('test');
if($m2->isPristine()) $m2->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);
var_dump($m2->getServerList());
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["port"]=>
    int(11211)
  }
}
```

Comment: WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOW memcached server lists are shared between class instances?? thanks sir, you've just changed my life.